# Python: defining functions on the fly

Tags: python, lambda

I have the following code:

```
 funcs = []
 for i in range(10):
   def func():
      print i
   funcs.append(func)

 for f in funcs:
   f()
```

The problem is that `func` is being overriden. Ie the output of the code is:

```
9
9
9
...
```

How would you solve this *without* defining new functions?

The optimal solution would be to change the name of the function. Ie:

```
for i in range(10):
   def func+i():
...
```

(or some other weird syntax)

Comment: Changing the name of the function isn't necessary.  Names are just names.  Once you assign it to funcs, the name of your functions might as well be `funcs[0]`, `funcs[1]`, `funcs[2]`, etc.  The only reason having differently named functions could matter is if you are messing around with `func.__name__`.  And you shouldn't be doing that anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is not that func is being overwritten, it's that the value of `i` is being evaluated when the function is called, not when it is defined.  If you want to evaluate `i` at definition time, put it in the function declaration, as a default argument to `func`.

```
funcs = []
for i in range(10):
    def func(value=i):
        print value
    funcs.append(func)

for f in funcs:
    f()
```

Default arguments are evaluated once, when the function is defined, so the incrementing loop will not affect them.  This would work just as well if you used

```
def func(i=i):
    print i
```

but I used the name `value` to make it clear which name is being used within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `func` from another function [is safest](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
for i in range(10):
    def func(j=i):
        print j
    funcs.append(func)
for f in funcs:
    f()
```