# List comprehension and functions

Tags: python, list, function, list-comprehension

I'm a little confusing when try something like this

```
b = [lambda x:x**i for i in range(11)]
```

When I then try `b[1](2)` I have 1024 as a result that is wrong. But when I write so

```
b = [(lambda i: lambda x:x**i)(i) for i in range(11)]
```

all is OK

```
>>> b[1](2)
2
>>> b[5](2)
32
```

It works fine but what's wrong in first code?

Comment: Your question is not a duplicate, but the reasoning is the same as in the answers to [this question]. [this question]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222466/python-defining-functions-on-the-fly/2222530#2222530 "this question."

Comment: Note that `lambda x, i=i: x**i` might be a more natural way to write what you phrase `lambda i: lambda x:x**i)(i)`. The default argument is evaluated when the function is defined.

Comment: -1: Too much time wrestling with `lambda`.  If a `lambda` doesn't seem to work, just remove the lambda and use a defined function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to [how closures in Python work](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271/).

The loop changes the value in the scope that *all* the functions share. Move generation of the function into a separate scope, i.e. function.

Answer (score 1):

It's a game of scopes.

In the first code, the "i" name in the lambda is only a reference. The value behind that reference gets altered as the for loop executes.

In the second code, there are two different scopes.